# make cut output a certain term when no delimiter found

Tags: cut, file-format

I am looking for extensions of files and cut simply gives the filename if the file has no extension
so I am looking to make cut give a "extensionless" when no '.' is found
I am using this as a refrence: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842254/how-can-i-find-all-of-the-distinct-file-extensions-in-a-folder-hierarchy the answers that ignore the files without extensions were no good as I needed to find those too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `zsh` shell:

```bash
print -rC1 ./**/*(.:e) | sed 's/^$/EXTENSIONLESS/' | sort | uniq -c
```

This prints all the extensions of all regular files in or under the current directory on a line each.  The empty extension is replaced by the text `EXTENSIONLESS` using `sed` before they are sorted and counted.

The `**` glob in `zsh` matches across `/` in pathnames ("recursively"), just like the same pattern in `bash` when the `globstar` shell option is set in that shell.

The `(.:e)` at the end of the pattern is a globbing qualifier that makes the preceding pattern only match regular files `(.)` and removes everything but the extension from each matching name (`:e`).

The same thing, but replacing extensionless filenames with `dummy.EXTENSIONLESS` within the globbing expression using a `e['...']` expression, and therefore getting rid of the `sed` call:

```bash
print -rC1 src/**/*(.e['[ -z $REPLY:e ] && REPLY=dummy.EXTENISONLESS']:e) | sort | uniq -c
```

---

In a non-`zsh` shell, you could use `find` with an in-line shell script to do the first few parts of the above pipeline:

```bash
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        name=${pathname##*/}
        case $name in
            *.?*)
                printf "%s\n" "${name##*.}" ;;
            *)
                echo EXTENSIONLESS
        esac
    done' sh {} + | sort | uniq -c
```

This uses `find` to find all regular files in or below the current directory.  For batches of these files, it calls an in-line shell script.  The script iterates over the current set of pathnames and extracts the filename portion of each into the variable `name`.  It then tests whether `$name` contains a dot followed by at least one other character. If there is a dot (followed by something) in the name, the part after the dot is printed; otherwise, the string `EXTENTSIONLESS` is printed.

The output of `find` is then sorted and counted in the same manner as before.

Note that the code above would call a name like `hello.` extension-less, while `.bashrc` would have the extension `bashrc`.  Change the pattern `*.?*` into `*?.?*` to require a character on either side of the dot (would make `.bashrc` count as extension-less).

Comment: this is the error I am getting when I run your code
```
Warning: unknown mime-type for "-rC1" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Warning: unknown mime-type for "./**/*(.:e)" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no such file "-rC1"
Error: no such file "./**/*(.:e)"
```

Comment: @stackingandexchangingwoohoo That's most likely because you're not using the `zsh` shell.

Comment: yes I am using bash and so does my workplace. still thanks for your answer someone will benefit from it.

Comment: @stackingandexchangingwoohoo See update.

Comment: I know this question was answered and closed but do you think there is anyway to have sort put EXTENSIONLESS at the end or start?

Comment: @stackingandexchangingwoohoo At the end or start of what? The filename? You could output the filename with any string attached to it with `printf "PREFIX%sSUFFIX\n" "$name"` in place of the `echo` in the code in the answer. Replace or remove `PREFIX` and `SUFFIX` with whatever you want.

Comment: no I meant when sort sorts out the list of extensions, it should put extensionless at the end or start instead of sorting it with the rest